# How to Create GPU SkImage in a Background Thread and Draw it on a Main SkSurface with OpenGL and Skia?

Tags: opengl-es, skiasharp, skia

I'm integrating Skia with OpenGL and facing a multi-threading challenge. I need to create a SkImage on a GPU in a background thread and render it on a SkSurface in the main thread. How can I safely share the OpenGL context and synchronize these operations between the threads? Any examples or best practices for this scenario in Skia and OpenGL would be very helpful.